# Is Re-enabling Misconduct Broken?

Tags: prison-architect

I recently disabled Misconduct in my [prison](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=696081249) using [these](http://prisonarchitectwiki.com/wiki/Cheats#How_to_have_a_misconduct-free_prison) instructions.

```
Find "EnabledMisconduct".
Next to the first time it comes up, it should say "true".
Change it to "false".
```

I did this about a week ago, during Update 6. It worked, and since then I have had no problems. Now I would like to *enable* it again. However, I cannot get anything to work. I looked in the save file and there is no `EnabledMisconduct` , `DisabledMisconduct`, or anything. This is making me think that it was removed in Update 7, but Introversion's changelog doesn't include anything even closely related.

**Does anyone know how to reenable Misconduct in Update 7?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more likely that the save files just exclude any features that are turned off instead of setting them explicitly to false.

Edit your save file, and add the following line somewhere between the other `Enabled` variables:

```
EnabledMisconduct    true
```

The `Enabled` variables are located between `ObjectId.next` and `ObjectsCentreAligned`. The save file should now look something like this:

[image: A pretty Prison Architect savefile]